# Passing args from main class

Tags: java

I'd like to ask easy question for somebody else but not me - 'cause i'm beginner.
I have a bit problem with passing arguments from 'main' to variable "server" under "public JavaApplication6()"
Simple code to make it clear:

```
public final class JavaApplication6 {
String server;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    }
    public  JavaApplication6() {
        server=main(args[0]);  ??                            //here is the problem - how to pass ?
    }
}
```

for example if i run this appplication with arguments "java JavaApplication6 someargument" under cmd i'd like to assign string someargument to variable 'server' so it would be :
server==someargument and then for example with System.out.println(server) display string 'someargument'.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Please explain clearly what the server is and what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass argument to main from the command line. not in the constructor. Constructor is used to initialize the class variables.

```
public final class JavaApplication6 {
    String server;

    //public constructor
    public  JavaApplication6(String s) {
        server=s;
    }
    //here is where the execution begins.
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //create a object of your class 

        JavaApplication6 app = new JavaApplication6(/*here is where you pass the arguments to the constructor*/ args[0]);


    }

}
```

Comment: Guys i can not accept all good answers so at the moement i will accept first good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public final class JavaApplication6 
{
  String server;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    JavaApplication6  obj = new JavaApplication6(args[0]);//pass zeroth argument
  }

  public  JavaApplication6(String s) {
    server = s; 
    System.out.println(s); 
  }
}
```

When you run the code , make sure you pass the argument otherwise it will throw exception.

Comment: Thanks for help guys. You helped me a lot. Now my application is coming to life. Thank you very much.  Regards

Comment: @admfotad Always Welcome.If you are satisfied don't forget to accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public final class JavaApplication6 {

String server;

public  JavaApplication6(String server) {
    this.server =  server;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JavaApplication6 jv = new JavaApplication6(args[0]);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;

public final class JavaApplication6  
{

    String server;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JavaApplication6  jApp = new JavaApplication6 (args[0]);
    }

    public JavaApplication6 (String s) {
        server = s;
    }
}
```

run the program like below

**java JavaApplication6 "localhost"**